# Custom Slide in animation when presenting navigation controller not working at all in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiviewanimation

So I've been following a couple tutorials on how to perform a custom animation when presenting a view controller. I currently have the following,

1. A class called TransitionManager which will be instantiated in **ViewController A** that will present the view
2. **ViewController A** that will present **ViewController B** in a navigation controller

According to all the tutorials i've read after setting the delegate in the presentation of the view, I should see my custom transition. However, the default animation is still used instead. I've tried moving the setting of the delegate before and after presenting with no avail

### Transition Manager Class

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
    let container = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

    // set up from 2D transforms that we'll use in the animation
    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: container.frame.width, y: 0)
    let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -container.frame.width, y: 0)

    // start the toView to the right of the screen
    if self.presenting {
        toView.transform = offScreenRight
    } else {
        toView.transform = offScreenLeft
    }


    // add the both views to our view controller
    container.addSubview(toView)
    container.addSubview(fromView)

    // get the duration of the animation
    // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
    // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
    let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    // perform the animation!
    // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
    // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
    // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

        if self.presenting {
            toView.transform = offScreenLeft
        } else {
            toView.transform = offScreenRight
        }
        toView.transform = .identity

    }, completion: { finished in

        // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

    })
    }

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.5
}

// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods

// return the animataor when presenting a viewcontroller
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    self.presenting = true
    return self
}

// return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    self.presenting = false
    return self
}

}
```

### Class ViewController A

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
func addButtonSelected() {
        let vc = ViewControllerB()
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
        nav.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't glean much from `perform slide in animation`.  Show your code.

Comment: ok added in an edit

Comment: You need to assign transitioningDelegate **before** you present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your methods to swift3-:

```
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return Transition()
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return Transition()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom`, mentioned in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621421-transitioningdelegate) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate).  I'm not sure if it matters, but I've also always set the transitioning delegate before calling `present`:

```
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
nav.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: hmmm, I did as suggested but there is no difference in the transition. It's still showing me the default presentation animation, bottom to top :(